# Array index ordering during declaration for performance

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran, intel-fortran

I require an array of the dimensions 100000 x 2 . Is there a performance advantage that can be gained (over the other) from declaring an array in one of the following formats in Fortran 90/95 :

Case (i):

```
real, dimension(100000,2) :: A
```

or case (ii):

```
real, dimension(2,100000) :: B
```

I believe case(ii) would have an advantage due to the column-major storage order of Fortran. I have run a few test cases and the result was as expected, but the difference in times are small. I would like someone to confirm this in the event of **both with and without ifort's vectorization**.
The compiler flags I used for the test cases were **-no-vec** for disabling vectorization and **-vec-report3** for report generation.

Comment: Why should there be an inherent difference? It depends how you use them in the code! How can anyone confirm your timings without your code?

Comment: The test code I wrote simply traverses through the entire array and performs an element-by-element operation (say an exponentiation). I admit I didn't really think about _what I want to do with the code_ like @chw21 said, but was focusing on which is faster for traversing through.

Comment: But it depends on HOW you traverse it!

Comment: So you're saying the generic rule, 'inner index should be iterated fastest' does not always apply in Fortran when I want to traverse through an entire array? I'm a bit confused now, when I think about the compiler vectorizing the code also..

Comment: Of course it does, but you didn't show that! And also, the operation that you do can have a big effect on the timings. And if you do some stencil operations, the whole thing changes completely (see *loop tiling* optimization)!

Answer (score 3):

In your case, the arrays are ordered like this:

```
A(1, 1) A(2, 1) A(3, 1) ... A(100000, 1) A(1, 2), A(2, 2) ... A(100000, 2)
B(1, 1) B(2, 1) B(1, 2) B(2, 2) ... B(1, 100000), B(2, 100000)
```

What is better depends on what you want to do with it:

```
mean(A(:, 1)) + mean(A(:, 2))
```

is faster than

```
mean(B(1, :)) + mean(B(2, :))
```

Because in `A` it can read in a lot of values at once, whereas for `B` it has to jump over every second value, then go back.

**But**

```
do i = 1, 100000
    C(i) = A(i, 1) - A(i, 2)
end do
```

is probably slower than

```
do i = 1, 100000
    C(i) = B(1, i) - B(2, i)
end do
```

Because for `B` it can read in the values sequentially whereas for `A` it has to jump forward and back 100000 values every time.

Comment: After the **but** : Not exactly. Your CPU can prefetch two streams, one for A(i,1) and one for A(i,2) as if it were two different arrays so it will not go back and forth. Also, these last two examples are memory bound so they should give exactly the same timings (limited by writing in `C(i)`).

Comment: @chw21 , Thanks, but I'm not so convinced about the part after **but**, I would be happier if you could include some comments about how and which of the cases would be vectorized by the compiler too.